# closures of the following subsets of the ordered square ?1

Tags: general-topology

Determine the closures of the  following  subsets of second order:

$(a)$ $E = \left\{\frac{1}{2}\times y\ |\ 0<y<1\right\}$

$(b)$ $D = \left\{x\times \frac{1}{2}\ |\ 0<x<1\right\}$

**My Attampt:** For $(a)$, since $E$ it is just the vertical open interval between $\frac12\times 0$ and $\frac12\times 1$. Any open interval containing $\frac12\times 0$ must ‘reach up’ into this interval, and any open interval containing $\frac12\times 1$ must ‘reach down’ into it, so both endpoints of the interval must be in its closure. Hence, $$Cl(E) = E\cup \left\{\frac{1}{2}\times 0, \frac{1}{2}\times 1\right\}$$

For $(b)$, since the set $D$ is the horizontal open interval between $0\times\frac12$ and $1\times\frac12\ $, any open interval containing $0 \times \frac12$ must ‘reach left’ to this interval and any open interval containing  $1\times\frac12$ must ‘reach right’ to it. Thus, both endpoints of the interval must be in its closure:

$$Cl(D) = D\cup \left\{0\times \frac{1}{2}, 1\times \frac {1}{2}\right\}$$

Is this correct. If not, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma  pliz help me

Comment: The answers are correct but your proofs are not convincing? What definitions and propositions do you have about closure? How can you make sure that your suggested answers line up with the definitions? How do you define a product topology?

Comment: @DanRobertson It’s an order topology here. Basic sets are open intervals in the lexicographic order $(x,y) < (u,v)$ iff $x< y$ or $x=y$ and $u < v$. Except in the minimum and maximum $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, where we have half open intervals ending at the min or max as basic sets. It’s quite different from the product topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ah thanks. Don’t think I’ve heard of that and I’d figured the word ‘ordered’ was thrown in at random

Comment: @DanRobertson No, it’s a classic example by Aleksandrov and Urysohn. It’s a compact non-metrisable space with a lot of nice properties. Even nicer is just the ordered set $(0,1) \times {0,1\} \cup \{(0,1)\} \cup \{(1,0)\}$ which is moreover hereditarily separable, and hereditarily LIndelöf but not second countable. This space is called “double arrow” in most of my books.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I should have been more clear that I agree that what you say is what OP means by ‘ordered square’. It may well be a classic example. I just don’t recall ever seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $E = \{\frac{1}{2}\} \times (0,1)$. A short check on cases shows that indeed all basic neighbourhoods of $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ have points in $E$, and so they lie in $\overline{E}$. And as $\{\frac{1}{2}\} \times [0,1]$ is closed (as a closed interval in an ordered space) we see that $E$ plus these two points is the whole closure.

As to $D = (0,1) \times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, the seeming endpoints $(1, \frac{1}{2})$ are and $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ are not in the closure: $((0,0), (0,1))$ is an open neighbourhood of $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ (an open interval) that misses $D$ and similarly for $((1, 0), (1,1))$ and $(1, \frac{1}{2})$.

But consider $(a,0)$ for $a \in (0,1]$:a basic neighbourhood of that point is an open interval (it’s not one of the two endpoints), with $(b,c) < (a,0) < (d,e)$ as endpoints. We cannot have $b=a$ as then we’d have $c <0$ which cannot be, so $b < a$. Pick some $b’$ with $b < b’  < a$. Then $(b,c) < (b’, \frac{1}{2}) < (a,0)$ (all determined by the first  coordinate), and so this open interval intersects $D$. This shows that $(0,1] \times \{0\} \subseteq \overline{D}$ as well.

A similar argument can be made symmetrically at the top edge to show that $[0,1) \times {1} \subseteq \overline{D}$ as well.

I claim that $\overline{D} = C:= D \cup (0,1]\times \{0\} \cup [0,1) \times \{1\}$ and one inclusion we have seen and the other follows from the fact that $$[0,1] \times [0,1]\setminus C = ([(0,0),(0,1)) \cup \bigcup_{x \in (0,1)} [((x,0), (x,\frac{1}{2})) \cup ((x,\frac{1}{2}),(x,1))] \cup ((1,0),(1,1)]$$ which is a union of basic open sets of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and so $C$ is closed.

Comment: one doubt is  that  by dictionary  order  as  $0 \times \frac {1}{2} $ < D < 1  $\times \frac {1}{2}$ now  again $0 \times \frac {1}{2} $ < $x \times \frac {1}{2}$ < 1  $\times \frac {1}{2}$  here  D   is  lies in  intersection....as  i mean  D  is  closed

Comment: @lomber I don’t get your point. I showed that $D$ is certainly not closed. And one open interval that intersects $D$ means nothing?

Comment: @    henno brandsma sir as  i understand  ur answer   but  little  bit   confusion is  that u said that $D = (0,1) \times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, the seeming endpoints $(1, \frac{1}{2})$ are and $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ are not in the closure......as    i  mean   by dictionary ordering   it will  be $0 \times \frac {1}{2} $ < D < 1  $\times \frac {1}{2}$ now  again $0 \times \frac {1}{2} $ < $x \times \frac {1}{2}$ < 1  $\times \frac {1}{2}$  here  D   is  lies in  intersection

Comment: @lomber $(0,0) < (0,\frac{1}{2}) <(0,1)$ and this open interval does not intersect $D$. So $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ does not lie in the closure of $D$.

Comment: ok  thanks  a lots   henno  sir

Answer (score 0):

a is correct answer, b is not.
That reaching up stuff needs to be defined.
D is closed.  x = 0 × .5 is not in closure of D because
x is in the open set {0} × [0,1) which misses D.
Similar for 1 × .5.  Note, every point of D is isolated.

Comment: im not getting that line x is in the open set {0} × [0, .2) which misses D...Can u elaborate more ??

Comment: @lomber.  It uses the fact that if D is closed and for all open U, (if x in U then U  $\cap$ D is not empty) implies x in D.

Comment: @lomber  Recall that the ordered square is not a bit like a geometric square, it is like a long line.

Comment: $D$ is **not** closed, see my answer.